# How to align rectangular image side by side with vertical pictures using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am working on some sort of website and I am stuck at the design of the homepage. The home page should have a vertical image and two rows of horizontal square images, I tried using an empty "col-md-4" tag to be counted on the second row of the square images but it didn't work the square images keeps on showing beneath the vertical image.

I am using Laravel Blade engine so I hope it won't be too complicated to read for non-Laravel programmers.

Here is my code

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 apple">
  @yield('apple') <!-- The Image in this tag is supposed to be vertical rectangle -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  @yield('samsung') <!-- This image is supposed to be horizontal beside the first third of apple image -->
  <!-- This one is working fine -->
</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @yield('empty')
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @yield('google') <!-- The problem goes here .. this one is supposed to be beneath the samsung image -->
    <!-- Beside the apple image which is vertically long -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    @yield('microsoft') <!-- And This image should be next to Google's image -->
    <!-- google's image and microsoft's image are aligned horizontally next to each other as planned -->
    <!-- The problem is with alignment of both of the images to be side by side with apple's image -->
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    @yield('lg')
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    @yield('huawei')
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    @yield('sony')
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    @yield('blackberry')
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, in order to have columns you need a row. Secondly, a row can have up to 12 column width in total, which means you can't add up to more than 12. More [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

An example with three columns would be this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Second, why don't you look for a ready-made [template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/) to use?

Comment: I am familiar with the rows .. didn't help, "why don't i look for a ready-made template ?" because i want to learn instead of depending on templates all the time .. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

why are you using many containers?

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
     <div class "col-md-4">.....
  </div>
</div>
```

containers is automatically in 12 column, unless you want

```
 <div class = "container-fluid"></div>
```

Try tutorial websites for bootstrap to know more

[Visit this](http://www.w3schools.com/)!

Comment: i edited my code is it is containing on container and row for every 12 column .. my problem isn't solved yet .. i want on image to be on the left side of the screen and to rows of squared images on the right .. please please just help with it and ignore whatever is irrelevant to this matter

Comment: `<div class = "row">

Comment: put it inside a `row` and the first `col-md-4`, put your picture into it and then the second,third is squared images.